# Display 'Pure HTML Dashboards' or 'Custom Components' using Analytics Api

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I need to display 'Pure HTML Dashboards' or 'Custom Components' as depicted in the following link https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/demos/embed-api/

I have google analytics account & it shows me the real time statistics perfectly for my website, but i need to display the same using the api as shown in the following link:
https://github.com/googleanalytics/embed-api-demos/blob/master/site/3-custom-components.html

I have replaced my client id in the following code:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
container: 'auth',
clientid: '623325626209-j1jm9d78ge0v4uf8b9cor31qsirungrq.apps.googleusercontent.com',
});
```

I also updated the end date to current date as follows:

```
query: {
'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
'dimensions': 'ga:date',
'start-date': '30daysAgo',
'end-date': '2014-09-05'
},
```

So when i run the code it shows a button "Access Google Analytics", when i click on it i get the following error:

1. That’s an error.

Error: origin_mismatch

Application: Project Default Service Account

You can email the developer of this application at: fz1990@gmail.com
Request Details

```
=
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=code token id_token gsession
redirect_uri=postmessage
cookie_policy=single_host_origin
proxy=oauth2relay591552393
state=524099008|0.3938720987
origin=http://localhost:27363
include_granted_scopes=true
client_id=656169223314-dbc8l4c7ro20hn8vcqqtd9rhd0e6arcb.apps.googleuserconte
```

Can somebody plss help me to fix this issue?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Origin mismatch is normally caused by the Javascript origins not being set correctly in the API project console.  You need to make sure that the Javascript origins match the domain from which your requests are coming and to which you are returning the user after sign in.

In your case you are still using the client_id from the tutorial you need to create your own.  More details can be found in the developer documentation for the embeded API in the ["Create a client ID and client secret" section](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide#client-id).

Basilcy you need to go to [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) and register your application.  The link above to the documentation will walk you though creating that.   Hint: don't for get to add a product name and email address.

At this time the Real-time API is still in beta you will need to apply for access to it.  [Real time reporting api private beta](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qfRFysCikpgCMGqgF3yXdUyQW4xAlLyjKuOoOEFN2Uw/viewform) fill out that form you wont hear anything from Google just wait 24 hours and give it a try it normally works by then.